# glstext-like command for page number in glossary list

Tags: xetex, indexing, ctex, glossary

I want to modify link texts, which are page numbers by default, in the glossary list. After some searching, I only find `glstextformat` which customises the link from main body to the glossary list. I also know that the `counter` option can set a different numbering. How do I further customise the link from the glossary to the document?

I've had a few failed attempts with `makeidx` and its variants, mostly because the custom texts contain special characters and is in UTF-8 which makeindex can't handle.

I've defined a new command that returns the custom text that I want, say `\sometext`, that depends on the position in the document, e.g. `\thesubsection`.

```
% use xelatex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{a}{name=a, description={}}

\newcommand\sometext{\thesubsection 节}

\begin{document}
index here \glsadd{a}

The link below should look like \sometext 

\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```